# Uncaught TypeError: in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-confirm

I am using confirm dialog of jquery-confirm.js plugin in my project.

but I caught below error :

```
"Uncaught TypeError: a(...).on is not a function
 at jquery-confirm.min.js:10
 at jquery-confirm.min.js:10"
```

after a long google I inserted the below jQuery CDN to the to of that function then that confirm dialog of the plugin jjquery-confirm is working fine, but i got an another error:

```
$() is not a function
```

the problem is that i have another document.ready() function like below

```
    $(function() {
    $("#successMsg").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
    });
    $("#failureMsg").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#validateMsg").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Below two jquery path is available on the page

```
<script src='/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I thought it because of the jquery version i used the below code, but there is no luck

```
$.noConflict();
```

The problem I could not able to use both the functions, It would be very much appreciable if any know the solution.

Comment: remove one of your 2 jqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You were getting `Uncaught TypeError: a(...).on is not a function` because you were using jquery version below 1.4.2 in which `.on` is not supported as it is introduced in version `1.7`.

So either change `on` to `bind` with jquery version `1.4.2`

or keep `on` as is and use latest jquery version i.e. cdn one.